# Show the relation between singular values of $A$ and $B^*AB$

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, singular-values, matrix-congruences

Proposition: For any nonsingular $A\in\mathbb{C^{n\times n}}$ and nonsingular $B\in\mathbb{C^{n\times n}}$, the following holds

$$\frac{\Re(x_i^*Ax_i)}{\sigma_i(A)}=\frac{\Re(y_j^*B^*ABy_j)}{\sigma_j(B^*AB)} \quad \text{for }i,j=1,2,\ldots,n.$$

where $[\sigma_1(A)\quad\sigma_2(A)\quad\cdots\quad\sigma_n(A)]$ are singular values of $A$, and $x_i(A)$ are corresponding singular vectors. Similarly $y_i(B^*AB)$ are corresponding singular vectors to $\sigma_i(B^*AB)$, where $[\sigma_1(B^*AB)\quad\sigma_2(B^*AB)\quad\cdots\quad\sigma_n(B^*AB)]$ are singular values of $B^*AB$.

Here $x_i$ are just columns of $V$ in svd of $A$, i.e., $A=U\Sigma V^*.$

---

I conjecture this after working with some engineering problem. Few simulations show that it holds for the examples I have tried. It is surprising for me that this proposition works even for one random example, but at the same time I was unable to prove it, so decided to share.

---

EDIT. I just found counter-example when $A,B$ random random nonsingular matrices. Turns out the matrices I used before were $A$ normal and $B$ positive definite.

Comment: Since it works for different indexes, I guess this means that the value $\frac{\Re(x_i^*Ax_i)}{\sigma_i(A)}$ is a constant in $i$ as well as $\frac{\Re(y_j^*B^*ABy_j)}{\sigma_j(B^*AB)}$ (which is the same constant), so in the end what you are stating equivalent to saying that for any $B$ non singular and any $\sigma$ and $x$ such that $\|x\|=1$ and $B^*ABx=\sigma x$, we have $\frac{\Re(x^* B^*AB x)}{\sigma}$ equal to that constant. Is this correct ?

Comment: @P.Quinton yes, I just found counter-example. Also, my friends showed me that $\Re({x_i^*Ax_i})/\sigma_i(A)$ is just real part of $i'$th diagonal element of unitary matrix which is obtained from polar decomposition